# pytest not discovering test in pyDev

Tags: pydev, pytest

I'm trying to build and run  *(selenium which is not relevant)*  test-suite with **pytest** framework.

I wrote a simple test as follows

```
class test_pqr():

    def test_lmn(self):
        print("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
        assert True

    def test_xyz(self):
        assert False

x= test_pqr()
x.test_lmn()
```

when I run it I got result...
[image]

if I run xyz as well... eg

```
    class test_pqr():

        def test_lmn(self):
            print("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
            assert True

        def test_xyz(self):
            assert False

    x= test_pqr()
    x.test_lmn()
    x.test_xyz()
```

get results as... [image]

what dose

> imported unittest before running pytest.main

error means?

why can't it discover test?

> collected 0 items

why are methods run only when there is error?

Comment: when run in command prompt getting same results, except pydev test runner error

Comment: Are you sharing all of `test_abc.py`?

Comment: yes those are only tests in test_abc.py

Answer (score 0):

After a long search and trial and error found the culprit.
You should name class **Test_*..**

> T in  UPPER CASE for Class

t in lower case for methods...

though tests are running as supposed, the error remains...