# PyTest not discovering new test module, but changes made in old test modules are reflected in execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest

**(This has been fixed, please read the edit at the bottom even if nobody submits an answer)**

I am writing tests for an app using PyTest, and had three test modules as of this evening. They work as expected, and any changes I make to them are reflected in the test execution (I intentionally put incorrect assertions to be completely sure). However, I added a new module this evening (which also begins with test_ and does not contain a class (so [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642618/pytest-not-discovering-test-in-pydev) does not apply), it is in fact almost identical in structure to one other test module) and no matter what I do PyTest refuses to discover it. I am using VS Code for development, but I tried running pytest from the terminal as well, to the same effect.

[This issue on GitHub](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/307) suggested I try `rm -rf .cache` which solved nothing. I tried removing all my `__pycache__` files just to be safe as well as the `.pytest_cache` file, to no avail. I checked the contents of the `.pytest_cache` file after removing and running `pytest` again, and none of the new tests are shown in the `nodeids`. I do not get any errors, in particular `test_grader.py`, `test_misc.py` and `test_solution_optimal.py` work perfectly fine. Here is [proof](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k6we7ydf3o5d8t4/Screenshot%202019-01-01%2021.52.16.jpg?dl=0) haha. `test_solution_student.py` is an exact copy of `test_solution_optimal.py` with a few deliberately incorrect assertions, but pytest won't discover it no matter what I do. Additionally, the `__pycache__` in the `tests` directory contains a .pyc file corresponding to `test_solution_student.py`, which is just plain strange to me. I even tried renaming the file to something different thinking the discovery might be ignoring the second test because they both start with `test_solution_`, but nope.

I only enabled pytest as recommended [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/unit-testing) and the autoTestDiscover.... is enabled as well. However since running pytest from the terminal does not result in the discovery of the last module either I doubt it's an issue with my VS code settings file.

Directory structure:

```
Top-Level Directory
├── .pytest_cache
│   └── v
├── Grader
│   ├── (Several files to be tested)
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
├── __pycache__
│   └── globals_store.cpython-37.pyc
├── graphs
│   ├── (Additional irrelevant files)
├── tests
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── test_grader.py
│   ├── test_misc.py
│   ├── test_solution_optimal.py
│   └── test_solution_student.py
└── venv
    ├── bin
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    └── share
```

I run `pytest` from the Top-Level Directory.

If somebody could give me a lead on what else I could try that might result in the test module being discovered I would forever be in your debt. I am not supposed to share the project since this is part of a homework assignment I am creating, but I am working on reproducing this issue in a dummy project.

**Edit:**

I "fixed" it; the issue lay with me duplicating the `test_solution_optimal` file, (duplicating code did smell funny to me, should have known to trust my intuition but I couldn't use that code out of the box and needed to make subtle modifications) which resulted in me redefining a fixture which I have now moved to a `conftest.py` file (I'm new to pytest, please forgive). I now know not to duplicate code (like, ever) but I am still curious as to why this was causing an issue which is why I chose not to add this as an answer to my question. If somebody could chime in with an explanation, be my guest :D

Comment: Well...I can't reproduce this (tried with a smaller example copying a test file in a virtual environment). Do you have this project anywhere you can share? Or give files/code that actually reproduce this? What version of python and pytest are you running? I assume you tried deleting *all* the `__pycache__` and other cache directories everywhere (not just in the tests directory).

Comment: I am not allowed to share this project since I am creating a homework assignment to be rolled out to students next Fall, but I will try to create another project with the issue and revert! Thanks so much :D

Comment: Python Version: 3.7.0, pytest version: 4.0.2

Comment: And indeed, I deleted all the cache files I could lay my hands on haha

Comment: Just tried with your version of python/pytest, still a no-go. I am on a mac, too. Cannot reproduce, sorry. If you can get a reproducible example that you can share I'd be interested in helping.

Comment: No problem, thanks for trying! I am considering copying the project and removing the part that isn't supposed to be public, brb

Comment: @MattMessersmith Fixed it and edited the question, feel free to chime in with an explanation! Thank you :D